# Type casting user input

Tags: objective-c, casting

I was trying to typecast in objective c but could only come up with the following sorce code which would not work. Does any one know a way to fix this to properly cast?

```
@interface AppController
{
NSTextField *myTextField;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSTextField *myTextField;
-(IBOutlet) foo
```

implementation:

```
-(IBOutlet) foo 
{
a = [myTextField.stringValue intValue]
float b = int(a)/3
int c = int(b)
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: what is not working as you expect?

Comment: when running the program it will return an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [reference page for using casts](http://visualcplus.blogspot.ca/2006/02/lesson-4-casting-data-types.html) in C-style languages.  Basically, your syntax uses `int` as if it were a function instead of a cast.

Comment: so if i were to use  ` int c = (int)b` that would work